# Chrome AppWindow Capture Mouse Event

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

An Chrome app window is originally not focused. When you click on the window's area, it gets focus. However, the mouse click event is not captured at this moment. I'm wondering how to capture the mouse event at the moment when the window gets focus. I mean just the mouse click event which brings the window from the background to the foreground.

Comment: use a window.onfocus event.  show code.

Comment: The focus event doesn't contain mouse position at all. How do I get the mouse position in this scenario? Moreover, focus event may not be triggered by the click event. I can't distinguish whether it's triggered by clicking on the window or what ever.

Comment: Yep. use that in conjunction with a click event.  here ya go: https://jsfiddle.net/MarcGuiselin/7vyey4Ld/1/  try clicking on the red result page a few times, then clicking somewhere else and clicking it again.

Comment: is that all you needed?

Comment: mark the question as done if you got the answer you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

use a window.onfocus event in conjunction with a click event.

here ya go: [jsfiddle.net/MarcGuiselin/7vyey4Ld/1](http://jsfiddle.net/MarcGuiselin/7vyey4Ld/1)

```
var justfocused=false;//true for 500ms after the page was focused
document.body.onclick=function(e){//onclick event always occurs after onfocus event
  if(justfocused){//if our window was just focused
    justfocusedevent(e);
    justfocused=false;//user has to refocus this tab for this function to run again
  }else{
    console.log("just a regular click");
  }
}

window.onfocus=function(){
  justfocused=true;
  setTimeout(function(){justfocused=false;},500);//reset just in case
  console.log("window focused");
}

function justfocusedevent(e){
    console.log("we just focused on this window at: ("+e.clientX+","+e.clientY+")");
}
```

Try clicking on the red result page a few times, then clicking somewhere else to unfocus the result window and clicking it again.